# AVMutableComposition - scaleTimeRange causing high bit-rate video to stutter on fast motion

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, avmutablecomposition

I am using scaleTimeRange:toDuration: to produce a fast-motion effect of upto 10x the original video speed. However I have noticed that videos with a higher bit-rate (say 20MBits/s and above) begin to stutter when played through an AVPlayer for anything above 4x the normal speed, enough to crash the AVPlayerLayer (disappear) if it runs for a while.

The code.

```
//initialize the player
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];

//load up the asset
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample-video" withExtension:@"mov"] options:nil];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"playable", @"hasProtectedContent", @"tracks"] completionHandler:
 ^{
     AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
     AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

     // composition set to play at 60fps
     videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,60);

     //add video track to composition
     AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

     //1080p composition
     CGSize renderSize = CGSizeMake(1920.0, 1080.0);
     CMTime currentTime = kCMTimeZero;
     CGFloat scale = 1.0;
     AVAssetTrack *assetTrack = nil;

     assetTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;

     [videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:assetTrack  atTime:currentTime error:nil];


     CMTimeRange scaleTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(currentTime, asset.duration);

     //Speed it up to 8x.
     CMTime scaledDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration,1.0/8.0);

     [videoTrack scaleTimeRange:scaleTimeRange toDuration:scaledDuration];

     AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

     //ensure video is scaled up/down to match the composition
     scale = renderSize.width/assetTrack.naturalSize.width;
     [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale) atTime:currentTime];


     AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
     videoInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration);
     videoInstruction.layerInstructions = @[ layerInstruction];

     videoComposition.instructions = @[videoInstruction];
     videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize;

     //pass the stuff to AVPlayer for playback
     self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
     self.playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition;
     [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];

     //playerView is a custom view with AVPlayerLayer, picked up from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW11

     [self.playerView setPlayer:self.player];

     //call [self.player play] when ready.


 }];
```

Some notes:

- All testing done on iPhone 6
- I am deliberately not adding any audio tracks to rule out the possibility of audio playing a part here.
- Normal bitrate videos (16Mbits/s on average) play fine on 10x
- Same composition code produces a smooth playback on an OSX application
- The stutter is more obvious with higher bitrates.
- All videos being tested are 1080p 60fps
- A high-bitrate video behaves well if opened in and exported to 1080, so to tone-down the bit-rate and maintain FPS.
- There is no rendering/exporting of video involved.

Has anyone else ran into this and know a way around?

Comment: Have you done this  ?

Comment: No luck around this yet mate. Guess it just comes down to hardware limitation, even for iPhone 6. I had to settle with limiting the speed to 4x for now.

Comment: The problem persists to date and had to rely on pre-computes post recording.

Comment: Sill happening?

Comment: I've played a video from 1/8 to 1/128 and it was faster with each doubling.